# Fetch current value of counter from backend: REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, backend

I would like to implement a simple route in the backend (REST API), where when I hit the endpoint (say `/api/counter`) for the first time I return the initial value of the counter **and** start a continuous increment process of the counter, such that whenever I hit the endpoint again, I would fetch the current value of the counter. Something like this

```
let counter = 0;
const fetchCurrentCounter = (req, res) => {
     setInterval(() => {
         counter++;
     }, 1000);
     res.json({counter});
}
```

How can I achieve this? Do I need different routes for this?

**PS**: My problem is not exactly a counter, but I phrased it with this very similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

When API is hit, your counter variable will be reset if it is defined in local scope. 
You can get it to work by defining variable in global scope, but again problem with this method is if your application get crashed or restarted, then your counter will be lost.

To do so, you can take any of the following approach

1. Make use of file system: When your API will hit, read the counter value from file, increment it and update into file and send response back. The cons of this approach is, it will increase overhead of file IO.
2. Make use of any database: You can make use of increment feature if database support($inc for mongodb while field = field + 1 in MySQL).